# Send is not defined, embed message problem (edit)

Tags: javascript, bots, embed, discord.js, message

```
`module.exports = {
    name: 'lat2',
    description: 'Let the Bot display latency/Response Time and API latency',
    execute(message, args) {
        const Embed1 = {
            color: "RANDOM",
            description: 'Pinging...',
        };

        const Embed2 = {
            color: "RANDOM",
            title: 'Latencies',
            description: `Latency/Response Time: ${send.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms\nAPI latency/"Remote Response time": ${Math.round(message.client.ws.ping)}ms`,
        };

        message.channel.send({ embed: Embed1 }).then(send => {
            send.edit({ embed: Embed2 });
        })
    }
};`
```

so can i do the whole thing embed or not? because... `send is not defined` the thing works fine in the non embed version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord embed messages are constructed differently. `send()` isn't an object, it's a function, you have to use `msg.edit`. You should make the color yourself.

```
`module.exports = {
  name: 'lat2',
  description: 'Let the Bot display latency/Response Time and API latency',
  execute(message, args) {
    let Embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#"+String(Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)))
      .setDescription("Pinging...")

    let Embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#"+String(Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)))
      .setTitle("Latencies")
      .setDescription(`Latency/Response Time: ${send.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms\nAPI latency/"Remote Response time": ${Math.round(message.client.ws.ping)}ms`)

    msg.channel.send(Embed1).then(msg => {
      msg.edit(Embed2);
    });
  }
};`
```

Comment: So now the error is: Discord is not defined and then when i put const Discord = require('discord.js'); into the execute its again: send is not defined you know why?

Comment: I haven't seen anyone using the `module.exports = { ... }`. I tested it in `client.on('message', msg => { ... })` after a specific condition and it worked fine, then i rewrote it to your kind of syntax thinking it would still work.